# How do you update an array that is inside a method so an array inside another method can perform accordingly

Tags: java, arrays, methods

The Java code that I'm building has two methods in it which has 3 arrays in it. The first method's 3 arrays after the method is called is updated accordingly. After calling the second method, the changes that happened in the first method are not represented in the second method.

For example:

```java
public class ticket_reservation {

    public static int [][] method1(){
        int [] array1 = { 1, 2, 3};
        int [] array2 = { 4, 5, 6, 7};
        int [] array3 = { 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};

        //code that involve the above 3 arrays

        int [][] array = { array1, array2, array3};
    
        return array;
    }

    public static int [][] method2(){
        int [] array1 = { 1, 2, 3};
        int [] array2 = { 4, 5, 6, 7};
        int [] array3 = { 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};
    
        //code that involve the above 3 arrays
    
        int [][] array = { array1, array2, array3};
    
        return array;
   }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        int [] array1 = { 1, 2, 3};
        int [] array2 = { 4, 5, 6, 7};
        int [] array3 = { 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};

        int [][] method1_array = method1();

        //code to make the 2D method1_array into 3 single dimention arrays
    
        int [][] method2_array = method2();
    
        //code to make the 2D method2_array into 3 single dimention arrays
    
        //this is where the problem arise. as the changes i made in the first method don't 
        //show in the second method
   }
}
```

I find it hard to find a solution here, as I expected the changes I made in the first method to also be made in the second method. I tried to write the code in the methods without using the arrays, but found it difficult.

Comment: Your code has this same 2D array declared and initialized 4 times, not good.  Better would be to declare the array once and passed to where it is needed.  Making changes on one object (one of the arrays) won't magically change a completely different object (the other arrays) since Java doesn't work that way. You should give your methods a 2D array parameter so that one single array can be created and then be passed into the methods.

Comment: Each method has its own arrays, so obviously the changes in one method do not propagate to the other method

Answer (score 0):

If the arrays are intended to be a shared resource then you will need to share them.  You could do this in a number of ways.

- You could define the array as static as well and then work with it
  within static methods.
- You could define the array as an instance variable, instantiate an
  instance within your driver (i.e. `main`), and work with the class
  instance.
- You could define the array within the `main` method and then
  pass it as an argument to those methods that work with it.